# Float округления

Tags: java, float

Забыл. 
360*x/100 где тип х float, результат  на калькуляторе 0,0895522392
в программе выдает 0.08955224, че он мне их так подрезал?

Comment: Используйте double

Comment: Float меньше знаков после запятой?...

Comment: float - 4 байта, double - 8, меньше байт - меньше точность

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите полный контроль над вычислениями, используйте специализированные типы, вместо встроенных

Например:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float x = 0.024875622f;
    int scale = 10;
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(360).multiply(new BigDecimal(x)).divide(new BigDecimal(100), scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
}
```